# Jenkins: automate the configuration of promote build plugin

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm trying to automate the complete process of a Jenkins instance.  The last hurdle I'm dealing with is configuring the promote build plugin.

[image]

How do I configure the settings in the image above using groovy or some programmatic way?  I tried to pull down the config via:

```
curl -v http://username:password@localhost:8080/job/neo/config.xml
```

But these settings are not in the XML response.

Answer (score 0):

I found a plugin DSL that will configure the promote build:

```
https://github.com/codecentric/job-dsl-promotions-plugin
```

I also found this playground to play around with Jenkins job configuration:

```
http://job-dsl.herokuapp.com/
```